# suppressing php imagecreatefromjpeg errors

Tags: php, gd, libjpeg, php-7.1, error-suppression

I have a script that processes uploaded jpgs, and for whatever reason, some jpgs don't seem to be compliant with whatever expectations imagecreatefromjpeg has. I suspect it is related to panorama images, but haven't had time to chase it down. I'm prepared to just skip defective jpgs, in favor of the 99% that work just fine. However, I can't seem to get my script to move passed one of these hiccups. Invariably, I get an inline error message every time one of these defective jpgs are uploaded in the pool of files:

> Error Number: 8
>
> Error Description: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG

Any idea what could possibly be going on here? I've done everything I can think of to prevent the error from derailing this operation... yet, here we are.

```
$filename = './uploads/'.$uniqIDStr.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $filename);
$imageResource = false;
try{
    ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true);
    $imageResource = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    if(!$imageResource){
        $imageResource=@imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Rejecting ' . $fileupload['name'] . ' because the file has some confusing properties...' . $e->getMessage(); 
    unlink($filename);
}
if($imageResource!=false){/***....***/}
```

[Click here for example jpg that derails everything](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BeyDXZfeGG_U4CKp58l6137EW8p6351W/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How about sharing an *"unhappy"* image?

Comment: Just added a link at the bottom for a "bad" jpg :)

Comment: Have you set a custom error handler? If so, read here... http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/2010/04/09/how-to-ignore-errors-in-a-custom-php-error-handler/

Comment: @MarkSetchell great catch, yes, I have a custom error handler, and the modification in the article you linked fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkSetchell your link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Set PHP to ignore jpeg warnings

ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);

on the line just before invoking imagecreatefromjpeg()